# woocommerce shopping cart not showing in wp-admin url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code on custom_dashboard.php
`woocommerce_mini_cart();`.  The cart is displayed with this url

`https://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/sweet-custom-dashboard/custom_dashboard.php`

but with this url i get an error

`https://www.example.co.uk/wp-admin/index.php?page=custom-dashboard`

This is the error i am getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart() on a non-object`

It seems the cart is not initializing with the admin url.

How do i solve?

Comment: can you  put your  code.

Comment: my code is just `woocommerce_mini_cart();` .. the shopping cart isn't displayed with the admin page redirect `wp_redirect( admin_url( 'index.php?page=custom-dashboard' ) );`  but the shopping cart is displayed if i put the plugin url

Comment: my guess is woocommerce cart hasn't been loaded yet.  How do i initialize the cart?